# real-time operating system scheduler

Tags: scheduler, rtos

I have to create scheduler for RTOS. How should I start?

What OS is good for writing scheduler? What operating systems should I chose?

How can I test scheduler, debug code?

Comment: What is your target platform/hardware? Your question makes little sense - the operating system *is* the scheduler. If you want to learn about RTOS and how they work read [µC/OS-II: The Real-Time Kernel, 2nd Edition](https://www.micrium.com/download/%c2%b5cos-ii-the-real-time-kernel-2nd-edition/).  If you have to ask how you test and debug code, you are probably not ready to write an RTOS - buy one, use a free one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to learn something by writing a `real time scheduler`, then you should start with reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)). Through this, you can learn different kinds of scheduler design and their applications. You can start with writing a small co-operative scheduler.

I will recommend you to use `freeRTOS`(as it is free and simple) first before jumping to write your own scheduler. There are user manual available online for free. Download them and go through them. Then, you can develop a application using `freeRTOS` APIs. Through this, you will understand the necessity of features provided by a `RTOS` (like process synchronization, priority of tasks, inter-process communication) and it's scheduler.

You may need to buy a development board support by freeRTOS or there is also [windows port](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Windows-Simulator-Emulator-for-Visual-Studio-and-Eclipse-MingW.html) available online. Then, you can start writing your own scheduler implementation. The `freeRTOS` source code which is available online for free can be used to aid your development. `FreeRTOS` is designed to be small and simple. The kernel itself consists of only three C files. To make the code readable, easy to port, and maintainable, it is written mostly in C, but there are a few assembly functions included where needed (mostly in architecture-specific scheduler routines).

Also, `POSIX` C library can also be used to understand `RTOS` and features required by any real time system. You can develop application using `POSIX` library to understand RTOS. Later, you can switch to any other RTOS.